# how to split after the every third space using explode?

Tags: php

I have a string as given below:

```
$str = "In order to successfully build your backlinks in a highly competitive industry (or if you're targeting highly competitive keywords), you have to get smart about your strategy. That means using the best back-link building tools available";
```

Now I want to split the string after every third word. That is I want..

```
split1 = in order to
split2 = successfully build your
split4 = backlinks in a
```

and so on till the end of the string.

I have already done it using preg_match_all but it isn't giving me what I want. So can someone help me out with it to split the string using the split() or preg_split or the explode() function.

Thank you

Comment: Use `explode` to split on every space. Then use `array_chunk` to collect groups of 3, and join them back together.

Comment: But array_chunk() would give the output aas array. But i wan't it to string only. Similar to what I have shown above.

Comment: That's why you join each chunk back together into a string.

Answer (score 8):

```
$split = explode(' ', $str); // Split up the whole string
$chunks = array_chunk($split, 3); // Make groups of 3 words
$result = array_map(function($chunk) { return implode(' ', $chunk); }, $chunks); // Put each group back together
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/Fes7xx)

`$result` is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => In order to
    [1] => successfully build your
    [2] => backlinks in a
    [3] => highly competitive industry
    [4] => (or if you're
    [5] => targeting highly competitive
    [6] => keywords), you have
    [7] => to get smart
    [8] => about your strategy.
    [9] => That means using
    [10] => the best back-link
    [11] => building tools available
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_split()` is a simple choice -- no chunking and iterating and mucking around.  One function call and done.

`\K` means forget the previously matched substring, this means only the 3rd space is "consumed" during the explosion.  `\S+` means one or more non-whitespace characters.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/T8lsM)) ([with word count not divisible by 3](https://3v4l.org/N6725))

```
$str = "In order to successfully build your backlinks in a highly competitive industry (or if you're targeting highly competitive keywords), you have to get smart about your strategy. That means using the best back-link building tools available";

var_export(
    preg_split('~(?:\S+\K ){3}~', $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'In order to',
  1 => 'successfully build your',
  2 => 'backlinks in a',
  3 => 'highly competitive industry',
  4 => '(or if you\'re',
  5 => 'targeting highly competitive',
  6 => 'keywords), you have',
  7 => 'to get smart',
  8 => 'about your strategy.',
  9 => 'That means using',
  10 => 'the best back-link',
  11 => 'building tools available',
)
```